# Loop through the returned output and make it autofill using Angular Material

Tags: angular, api, angular-material

When I call the Web API it returns the results and on typescript file refined the results and they look like below
(the output captured from the console)

```
this.address [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

[object Array]: [Array]

0: Array

0: Object
Description: "Sherbrooke, QC, J1E 3X3"
Highlight: "0-4"
Id: "CA|CP|A|9844581"
IsRetrievable: true
Text: "6366-1150 Rue Des Quatre-Saisons"

__proto__: Object

1: Object
Description: "Orléans, ON, K1C 2G2"
Highlight: "0-4"
Id: "CA|CP|A|69450|FRE"
IsRetrievable: true
Text: "6366 Av Mattice"

__proto__: Object
```

Am trying to iterate through this and do the autocomplete of the information that I got

I was able to do the iteration as below using div and populating the address information in the textboxes.

```
<div>
      <div *ngFor="let row of addresses; let i = index" >
        <div
          *ngFor="let addon of row; let j = index"
        >
          <input [value]="addresses[i][j].Text"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But was not able to do using the mat-option. How can I do something like addresses[I][j] using mat-option

```
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let addressess of addresses.Items;let i=index" [value]="addressess[i].Text">
            {{ addressess[i].Text }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Please suggest what I can do differently , so that I can autofill the address information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you seem to have is an array of 'array of objects'... which is why you would need an extra ngFor (via ng-container) to traverse the top level array before you get to your 'array of objects'.

relevant changes in the HTML:

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <ng-container *ngFor='let filteredStates of states'>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates" [value]="state.name">
    <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="state.flag" height="25">
    <span>{{state.name}}</span> |
    <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
  </mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

In the code, I have also printed the array simply to better showcase the structure.

- the [code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sgggxx?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html) for an *an array of 'array of objects'*
- the [code sample](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples) for an *array of objects*

Comment: Hi Akber, That's solved my problem. When I select one of the values from the autocomplete , can I fill remaining fields like other address information.And on change of something on the autocomplete line how can I wipe out remaining fields as something is getting changed on selection side I need to wipe out other address related fields

Comment: the auto complete feature of the browser till take care of that - especially if the fields are from a standard form like first name, last name, age, gender etc etc